# I think here use "Besides" is incorrect

Tags: word-difference

> Besides a brief fight with Vietnam, the entire post-World War II
>   period for China has been peaceful.

[Source](http://www.businessinsider.com/retiring-chinese-general-reveals-chinas-greatest-military-weakness-2018-6)

I think here it should use "except" or "except for".

Comment: Are you asking the question for *besides* or *except?*

Comment: I agree *except for* sounds better, but many English speakers will use *besides* in this situation.  I would probably say *aside from*.  Although the sentence itself is only true for a very particular definition of *peaceful*.

Comment: @MaulikV I think I can distinguish the two words. I want to know if the English Editor made a mistake.

Comment: No "except" to start a sentence, only "except for".

Comment: @MvLog Except you can! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used **besides** in just this way my entire life, and heard other people use it similarly. So, for me anyway, I would not say that it's strange or unusual at all. While it would be more common for me to use *except* in the middle of a sentence, I will more often introduce a sentence with **besides**. (I almost never say *aside from* . . .)

The use of **besides** is perfectly fine, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/besides):

> *preposition*
>   Popularity: Top 30% of words
>
> 1 : other than, except · no one *besides* us · Nothing *besides* a miracle could help them.
>
> 2 : together with · a decision that, *besides* being practical, is morally right
>
> She wants to learn other languages *besides* English and French.
>   *Besides* its famous cakes, the bakery also makes delicious breads and cookies.
>   These salads are delicious *besides* being healthy.
>   I'm not ready to get married yet. *Besides* which, I enjoy living alone.

And **besides** is also fine according to [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/besides):

> preposition
>
> In addition to; apart from.
>
> ‘I have no other family besides my parents’
>   ‘besides being a player, he was my friend’
>   ‘Candidates were asked which nation, besides Canada, concerns them the most.’
>   ‘There was no sense in trying to put the blame on anyone besides their parents.’

Comment: It's a shame the other answer was accepted, because I feel like this one is the more correct one. I don't think this usage of _besides_ should be classified as a "mistake".

Comment: In Chinese, the "besides" and "except" are the same word: 除了. So, In our examination, distinguish them is a basic skill.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The usage is strange and as Andrew said and you believe, *aside from, except for* would sound better.

Here it what [Cambridge Dictionary says](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/besides) while stating the difference between *'beside'* and *'besides.'*

> *besides is a preposition or linking adverb. It means **in addition to** or **also.***

Obviously, there are two sides of the story - peace and war. And, they are opposite; so, there's no question of telling that *in addition/also*.

Comment: Except that _besides_ can mean _except for_. See [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/besides).

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right to be uncomfortable, but I don't think it is for the reasons stated above.

Here is another way to look at it. Besides is sometimes rendered as "other than (for)", as in:

> Other than Vietnam (for), there are no Asian countries with the letter V in their name. (I think...?)
>
> Besides Vietnam, there are no Asian countries with the letter V in their name. (I think...?)

I think that is what is intended in this sentence.

> Other than a brief fight with Vietnam, the entire post-World War II period for China has been peaceful.

However, as you can see, this makes me think this should be:

> Other than **for during** a brief fight with Vietnam, the entire post-World War II period for China has been peaceful.

This, I think, is the reason for your discomfort. A more detailed explanation follows.

Imagine putting the besides at the end of the original sentence:

> The entire post-World War II period for China has been peaceful besides a brief fight with Vietnam.

This sounds strange. Why? I think it is because the prepositional phrase besides seems to modify peaceful, which is not a noun.

So let's try this:

> The entire post-World War II period for China, besides a brief fight with Vietnam, has been peaceful.

This shows that the comparison is awkward. Let's try to fix this with **for**.

> The entire post-World War II period for China, besides **for** a brief fight with Vietnam, has been peaceful.

Both of these have the problem of the prepositional phrase starting "besides..." being separated from the word period which it is modifying. This is bad form, so maybe we need this:

> The entire post-World War II period, besides **for** a brief fight with Vietnam, for China has been peaceful.

Awkward. Let's bring for China to the end.

> The entire post-World War II period, besides **for** a brief fight with Vietnam, has been peaceful for China.

Better, but still not quite right. Why? Because a fight is not a period, so they oughtn't be compared. That is why **during** is necessary above.

Leading to:

> The entire post-World War II period, besides **for during** a brief fight with Vietnam, has been peaceful for China.

Now "peaceful" is kind of far from "has been". Revenons a nos moutons:

> Besides **for during** a brief fight with Vietnam, the entire post-World War II period has been peaceful for China.

I woud prefer:

> Besides **for during** a brief fight with Vietnam, the entire post-World War II period has been a peaceful one for China.

Sounds lovely.